# Cannot get the libphonenumber npm package working, fs.readFileSync is not a function error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, browserify, libphonenumber

I'm trying to use the [googlei18n libphonenumber library](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) for phone number validation. I'm using the npm package via `npm i libphonenumber`, but when I do this:

```
var libphonenumber = require('libphonenumber')
```

I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function`

Even if I add `browserify-fs` as a dep and require it before `libphonenumber`, I still get the error. I've been googling around and cannot figure out what this error even means, really, except that it's some kind of directory function. Shouldn't `libphonenumber` be a script, not a file directory?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module you've installed is explicitly a port of the Google code **to node** and not for the browser. If you want to use it in the browser don't install it from npm but download it directly from Google's repository. If you want to use it with browserify take a look a [browserify-shim](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim) which allows you to bundle libraries which do not use CommonJS modules.

See also https://github.com/mattbornski/libphonenumber/issues/17

Comment: do you have any idea how it work on webpack? I have similar problem regards to `fs`. Check it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37608118/uncaught-typeerror-fs-readfilesync-is-not-a-function